# raise ElementDoesNotExist stack.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my RPN calculator:

def calculate_onp(onp):
    from stack.stack import Stack

```
OPERATORS = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
s = Stack()

lista = onp.split(" ")

index = None

for i in range(1, len(onp)):
    index = i - 1
    if lista[index] in OPERATORS:
        if lista[index] == OPERATORS[0]:
            num1 = s.pop()
            num2 = s.pop()
            wyn = int(num1) + int(num2)
            s.push(wyn)

        elif lista[index] == OPERATORS[1]:
            num1 = s.pop()
            num2 = s.pop()
            wyn = int(num1) - int(num2)
            s.push(wyn)

        elif lista[index] == OPERATORS[2]:
            num1 = s.pop()
            num2 = s.pop()
            wyn = int(num1) * int(num2)
            s.push(wyn)

        elif lista[index] == OPERATORS[3]:
            num1 = s.pop()
            num2 = s.pop()
            wyn = int(num1) / int(num2)
            s.push(wyn)

        else:
            return 'ERROR'

else:
    s.push(lista[index])

return int(s.pop())
```

I added a stack implementation to this:

```
from stack.exceptions import ElementDoesNotExist

class Stack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.stack)

    def push(self, s):
        return self.stack.append(s)

    def pop(self):
        if len(self.stack) == 0:
            raise ElementDoesNotExist
        else:
            return self.stack.pop()

    def show_list(self):
        print(self.stack)
```

And exceptions:

for stack:

```
class ElementDoesNotExist(Exception):
    pass
```

for rpn:

```
class OnpException(Exception):
    pass
```

class OnpMissingOperationArgument(OnpException):
        pass

class OnpMissingNumericArgument(OnpException):
        pass

After running this:

```
        File "/home/maciek/PycharmProjects/Calc/stack/stack.py", line 16, in pop
    raise ElementDoesNotExist
stack.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `len(self.stack) == 0`

Comment: After running what?

Answer (score 0):

your pop function has called to a function named `len(self.stack)`. But It doesn't exists. so try on Changing the name `def __len__(self):` to `def len(self):`